# Tensorflow android example won't build

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build the android example from tensorflow but keep running into an annoying build error. My steps so far:

- installed android studio for the SDK. (v24)
- downloaded android NDK 10e (other versions don't seem to work)
- aditionally installed SDK build tools 23.0.1 (v24 doesn't seem to work)
- added an assets folder to the android example with the inception model
- edited the WORKSPACE file to point to the NDK/SDK locations.

I tried several versions of TF, but I keep getting the error. Any ideas?

The error:

```
C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf//:protobuf' failed: namespace-sandbox failed: error executing command /home/sander/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sander/577a8dcd97360f56540bc1f3f08ac240/tf-cat-face/_bin/namespace-sandbox ... (remaining 51 argument(s) skipped).
src/main/tools/namespace-sandbox.c:697: execvp(argv[0], argv): No such file or directory
Target //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

Comment: Are you able to get any other example (e.g. MNIST) working with Tensorflow? Not sure if this is a problem of android example, or tensorflow installation, or bazel.

Comment: Yes the MNIST example seems to build fine. That's what's confusing to me.

Comment: The label image example, which also uses inception, also builds. I'm quite confused and stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bazel creates a sandbox for each compilation step, so your build doesn't include anything unintentional.  However, last time I checked, TF can't use the sandbox because its build isn't completely hermetic.  The errors you're getting are sandboxing errors (it can't find something that's supposed to be in the sandbox) so you can turn the sandbox off with `--genrule_strategy=standalone` and `--spawn_strategy=standalone` flags, e.g.,

```
bazel build --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone //path/to/your:target
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick way to build the TensorFlow Android demo app, check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@daj/creating-an-image-classifier-on-android-using-tensorflow-part-2-9ec0698d801e#.cq90jj4jd) I wrote.

The articles explain more, but I created [this Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/danjarvis/tensorflow-android/) which contains all the dependencies you need so that you can just pull the Docker image and build the Android demo app.

The one gotcha I found was that I needed to pass the `--local_resources` option to ensure that builds succeed inside Docker (otherwise they run out of memory, even on my 3.1 GHz, 16GB RAM Macbook Pro):

```
bazel build -c opt --local_resources 4096,4.0,1.0 -j 1 //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
```